# Create a dataframe from a dictionary with multiple keys and values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

So I have a dictionary with 20 keys, all structured like so (same length):

```
{'head':              X         Y         Z
 0    -0.203363  1.554352  1.102800
 1    -0.203410  1.554336  1.103019
 2    -0.203449  1.554318  1.103236
 3    -0.203475  1.554299  1.103446
 4    -0.203484  1.554278  1.103648
 ...        ...       ...       ...
 7441 -0.223008  1.542740  0.598634
 7442 -0.222734  1.542608  0.599076
 7443 -0.222466  1.542475  0.599520
 7444 -0.222207  1.542346  0.599956
 7445 -0.221962  1.542225  0.600375
```

I'm trying to convert this dictionary to a dataframe, but I'm having trouble with getting the output I want. What I want is a dataframe structured like so: `columns = [headX, headY, headZ etc.]` and rows being the `0-7445 rows`.

Is that possible? I've tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient="columns")
```

And different variations of that, but can't get the desired output.

Any help will be great!

**EDIT:** The output I want has 60 columns in total, i.e. from each of the 20 keys, I want an `X, Y, Z` for each of them. So columns would be: `[key1X, key1Y, key1Z, key2X, key2Y, key2Z, ...]`. So the dataframe will be `60 columns x 7446 rows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `axis=1` and then flatten Multiindex by `f-string`s:

```
df = pd.concat(d, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
```

Comment: That concatenated all the columns into just three, so created columns `X, Y, Z` when what I want is for each of the 20 keys to have each of their `X, Y, Z` as columns, so 60 columns in total. Does that make sense?